# R Time Intervals: Grouping by hour of day when sample goes over the hour mark

Tags: r, datetime, time, intervals, lubridate

I have video data for the durations of two bird behaviors, when the bird is on the nest and when the bird is off the nest. For my analysis, I need to get durations on and off the nest per hour. However, often times the different behaviors overlap the hour mark. For example the bird is on the nest from 4:10-4:42 and 4:50 - 5:20 and I need to separate the second period to 4:50-5:00 and 5:00-5:20 so that I can sum per hour. I've looked for quite some time with package lubridate, but did not see a way to do this but think there has got to be something out there. Any suggestions?

Sample data is below. "off.time.diff" is the difference in seconds between the "off.bout.id", and same for "on.time.diff". Using an example here, the bird is on from 17:25:39 to 18:03:29. I can get the total time on (2270 seconds), but can't figure out how to separate this per hour.

```
Event   DT.event        off.bout.ID  on.bout.ID  off.time.diff  on.time.diff
off     4/27/12 17:25:13    1          0           NA               NA
on      4/27/12 17:25:39    1          1           26               NA
off     4/27/12 18:03:29    2          1           NA              2270
on      4/27/12 18:03:57    2          2           28               NA
off     4/27/12 19:41:16    3          2           NA              5839
on      4/27/12 19:43:50    3          3           154              NA
off     4/28/12 6:23:57     4          3           NA              38407
on      4/28/12 6:32:13     4          4           496              NA
off     4/28/12 6:40:20     5          4           NA              487
on      4/28/12 6:40:48     5          5           28               NA
off     4/28/12 8:16:07     6          5           NA              5719
```

Comment: Hi EagleEye. Did one of the suggested solutions answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more beautiful solution than Dario's can be made using tidyverse:

*Reading data*

```
a =  
        read.csv(header = F, sep = ";",
                 col.names = c("Event","DT.event","off.bout.ID","on.bout.ID","off.time.diff","on.time.diff"),
                 text = gsub(pattern = "\\s+{2}",replacement = ";", 
                             x="off     4/27/12 17:25:13    1          0           NA               NA
                        on      4/27/12 17:25:39    1          1           26               NA
                        off     4/27/12 18:03:29    2          1           NA               2270
                        on      4/27/12 18:03:57    2          2           28               NA
                        off     4/27/12 19:41:16    3          2           NA               5839
                        on      4/27/12 19:43:50    3          3           154              NA
                        off     4/28/12 6:23:57     4          3           NA               38407
                        on      4/28/12 6:32:13     4          4           496              NA
                        off     4/28/12 6:40:20     5          4           NA               487
                        on      4/28/12 6:40:48     5          5           28               NA
                        off     4/28/12 8:16:07     6          5           NA               5719"
                 )
        ) 

a$DT.event <- mdy_hms(a$DT.event)
```

*Adding a new row containing the hours that can be of interest*

```
b <- a %>% select(DT.event) %>%
        mutate(DT.event = floor_date(DT.event,"hours")) %>%
        group_by(DT.event) %>%
        summarise() %>%
        full_join(a) %>%
        arrange(DT.event)
```

*Finding differences*

```
c <- b %>% fill(Event, .direction = "up") %>%
        mutate(on.time.diff.hour = ifelse(Event == "off",
                                          difftime(DT.event, lag(DT.event),
                                                   "secs"), NA))
```

You just need to pay attention to check weather you got an extra value in the second line (as there was no on before it).

*The results*

```
# A tibble: 16 x 7
   DT.event            Event off.bout.ID on.bout.ID off.time.diff on.time.diff on.time.diff.hour
   <dttm>              <fct>       <int>      <int>         <int>        <int>             <dbl>
 1 2012-04-27 17:00:00 off            NA         NA            NA           NA                NA
 2 2012-04-27 17:25:13 off             1          0            NA           NA              1513
 3 2012-04-27 17:25:39 on              1          1            26           NA                NA
 4 2012-04-27 18:00:00 off            NA         NA            NA           NA              2061
 5 2012-04-27 18:03:29 off             2          1            NA         2270               209
 6 2012-04-27 18:03:57 on              2          2            28           NA                NA
 7 2012-04-27 19:00:00 off            NA         NA            NA           NA              3363
 8 2012-04-27 19:41:16 off             3          2            NA         5839              2476
 9 2012-04-27 19:43:50 on              3          3           154           NA                NA
10 2012-04-28 06:00:00 off            NA         NA            NA           NA             36970
11 2012-04-28 06:23:57 off             4          3            NA        38407              1437
12 2012-04-28 06:32:13 on              4          4           496           NA                NA
13 2012-04-28 06:40:20 off             5          4            NA          487               487
14 2012-04-28 06:40:48 on              5          5            28           NA                NA
15 2012-04-28 08:00:00 off            NA         NA            NA           NA              4752
16 2012-04-28 08:16:07 off             6          5            NA         5719               967
```

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit dense, but I don't see how this separates the observations into the *hour bins*. If this does work i'd prefer a dplyr solution... ;)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I was able to tweak it a bit to fix the extra time issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind my suggestion is to check for each event how many full hour marks were passed and insert an extra row for each hour and changing the times accordingly...

Load example data:

```
df <- read.table(text='Event   DT.event        off.bout.ID  on.bout.ID  off.time.diff  on.time.diff
off     4/27/12-17:25:13    1          0           NA               NA
on      4/27/12-17:25:39    1          1           26               NA
off     4/27/12-18:03:29    2          1           NA              2270
on      4/27/12-18:03:57    2          2           28               NA
off     4/27/12-19:41:16    3          2           NA              5839
on      4/27/12-19:43:50    3          3           154              NA
off     4/28/12-6:23:57     4          3           NA              38407
on      4/28/12-6:32:13     4          4           496              NA
off     4/28/12-6:40:20     5          4           NA              487
on      4/28/12-6:40:48     5          5           28               NA
off     4/28/12-8:16:07     6          5           NA              5719', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Set datetime variable. Adapt `tz` argument if neccessary:

```
df$DT.event <- as.POSIXct(df$DT.event, format = "%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S")


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# reshape data
# 
df2 <- df %>%
  select(Event, DT.event, on.bout.ID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Event,
              values_from = DT.event) %>% 
  select(on.bout.ID, on, off)
```

`df2` is some of the information of `df` in wider form:

> ```
>   on.bout.ID on                  off                
>        <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
> 1          0 NA                  2012-04-27 17:25:13
> 2          1 2012-04-27 17:25:39 2012-04-27 18:03:29
> 3          2 2012-04-27 18:03:57 2012-04-27 19:41:16
> 4          3 2012-04-27 19:43:50 2012-04-28 06:23:57
> 5          4 2012-04-28 06:32:13 2012-04-28 06:40:20
> 6          5 2012-04-28 06:40:48 2012-04-28 08:16:07
> ```

```
# Make a copy so we don't mutate the object we are using to iterate
#
df3 <- df2

for (i in seq_along(df2$on.bout.ID)) {

  # extract current iterations start and end time
  # 
  id <- df2$on.bout.ID[i]
  from <- df2$on[i]
  to <- df2$off[i]

  # calculate number of rows to insert
  # 
  hoursDiff <- as.numeric(format(to, "%H")) - as.numeric(format(from , "%H"))

  # compensate for crossing of midnight (00:00AM)
  # by adding 24
  #
  hoursDiff <- as.integer(difftime(as.Date(to), as.Date(from), unit="days")) * 24 + hoursDiff

  # if there is at least on pass of the full hour, insert a copy of the
  # current row but adapt on and off times
  # 
  if (!is.na(hoursDiff) & hoursDiff > 0) {
    for (hour in 1:hoursDiff) {

      # startime of this additional row
      # 
      fromTime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(format(from  + 3600 * hour, "%m/%d/%y-%H"), ":00:00"), format="%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S")

      # Maximal endtime of this additional row
      # 
      toTime <- fromTime + 3599

      # copy current line
      # 
      insert <- df2[i, ]

      # set start time for this new row to full hour
      #
      insert$on <- fromTime

      # if this is the last row to insert do NOT adapt off time
      # 
      if (!(toTime > to)) {
        insert$off <- toTime
      } 

      # add additional row
      # 
      df3 <- rbind(df3, insert)
    }

  # set off-time for the current line to end of first hour
  # 
  df3[df3$on.bout.ID == id & df3$on == from & df3$off == to,]$off <-  as.POSIXct(paste0(format(from, "%m/%d/%y-%H"), ":59:59"), format="%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S")
  }
}

# Use `dplyr` to sort result
#
library(dplyr)    
df3 %>% arrange(on.bout.ID, on)
```

> ```
>     # A tibble: 21 x 3
>       on.bout.ID on                  off                
>            <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
>     1          0 NA                  2012-04-27 17:25:13
>     2          1 2012-04-27 17:25:39 2012-04-27 17:59:59
>     3          1 2012-04-27 18:00:00 2012-04-27 18:03:29
>     4          2 2012-04-27 18:03:57 2012-04-27 18:59:59
>     5          2 2012-04-27 19:00:00 2012-04-27 19:41:16
>     6          3 2012-04-27 19:43:50 2012-04-27 19:59:59
>     7          3 2012-04-27 20:00:00 2012-04-27 20:59:59
>     8          3 2012-04-27 21:00:00 2012-04-27 21:59:59
>     9          3 2012-04-27 22:00:00 2012-04-27 22:59:59
>     10          3 2012-04-27 23:00:00 2012-04-27 23:59:59
>     # … with 11 more rows
> ```

Is it pretty? No!
Does it work? I think so

## Edit:

added

```
 hoursDiff <- as.integer(difftime(as.Date(to), as.Date(from), unit="days")) * 24 + hoursDiff
```

To extend functionality for crossing of midnight(s)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Yours data
a =  
  read.csv(header = F, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F,
           col.names = c("Event","DT.event","off.bout.ID","on.bout.ID","off.time.diff","on.time.diff"),
           text = gsub(pattern = "\\s+{2}",replacement = ";", 
                       x="off     4/27/12 17:25:13    1          0           NA               NA
                        on      4/27/12 17:25:39    1          1           26               NA
                        off     4/27/12 18:03:29    2          1           NA               2270
                        on      4/27/12 18:03:57    2          2           28               NA
                        off     4/27/12 19:41:16    3          2           NA               5839
                        on      4/27/12 19:43:50    3          3           154              NA
                        off     4/28/12 6:23:57     4          3           NA               38407
                        on      4/28/12 6:32:13     4          4           496              NA
                        off     4/28/12 6:40:20     5          4           NA               487
                        on      4/28/12 6:40:48     5          5           28               NA
                        off     4/28/12 8:16:07     6          5           NA               5719"
           )
  ) %>% mutate(DT.event = as.POSIXct(DT.event, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
              )
# Ordering by time, if it isn't ordered
a = a[order(a$DT.event),]

# Build a trick column to calculate time difs with 'next_event'
a[,"next_eve"] = as.POSIXct(c(a$DT.event[2:nrow(a)],NA))

# Build column with time difference by "complete" hours
a = a %>%
      mutate(dif_comp_hour_sec =  
               case_when(
                 floor_date(next_eve,unit = "hour") > floor_date(next_eve,unit = "hour") ~ as.numeric(floor_date(next_eve,unit = "hour") - DT.event),
                                  T ~ as.numeric(next_eve - DT.event  )
                                 )
            )
```

You can use column "Event" to split in to on/off columns again if you need.

Here the output:

```
#    Event          DT.event off.bout.ID on.bout.ID off.time.diff on.time.diff          next_eve dif_comp_hour_sec
# 1    off 12-04-27 17:25:13           1          0            NA           NA 12-04-27 17:25:39                26
# 2     on 12-04-27 17:25:39           1          1            26           NA 12-04-27 18:03:29              2270
# 3    off 12-04-27 18:03:29           2          1            NA         2270 12-04-27 18:03:57                28
# 4     on 12-04-27 18:03:57           2          2            28           NA 12-04-27 19:41:16              5839
# 5    off 12-04-27 19:41:16           3          2            NA         5839 12-04-27 19:43:50               154
# 6     on 12-04-27 19:43:50           3          3           154           NA 12-04-28 06:23:57             38407
# 7    off 12-04-28 06:23:57           4          3            NA        38407 12-04-28 06:32:13               496
# 8     on 12-04-28 06:32:13           4          4           496           NA 12-04-28 06:40:20               487
# 9    off 12-04-28 06:40:20           5          4            NA          487 12-04-28 06:40:48                28
# 10    on 12-04-28 06:40:48           5          5            28           NA 12-04-28 08:16:07              5719
# 11   off 12-04-28 08:16:07           6          5            NA         5719              <NA>                NA
```

Comment: No, because the time differences are not separated into the hour "bins" yet. For example, the on time duration of 2,270 seconds starts at 17:25:39 and goes to 18:03:57. So I need to cut off that 3 mins, 29 secs to be a part of the 18:00 hour "bin." I have many many more days of data than just these 11 events, so I would like to automate this instead of say, subtracting that 3 mins 29 secs from the 2,270 on-nest length (and doing that subtraction from every event that overlaps an hour by hand).

Comment: Hmm, now I think  I got it.
Your espected bins are [00:00:00; 01:00:00) .... [13:00:00; 14:00:00) ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
#create a lookup table of hourly data (to be dyn, you can use round(min()-1hr) and round(max()+1hr) to generate your hourly data
hourly <- data.table(HOUR=seq(as.POSIXct("20120427 170000", format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S"), 
    as.POSIXct("20120428 090000", format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S"), 
    by="1 hour"))[, DT.event := HOUR]

#get end of event from the row below
DT[, endDT.event := shift(DT.event, -1L)]

#perform rolling join to find the closest hour after this event time
DT[, hr_aft := hourly[.SD, on=.(DT.event), roll=-Inf, HOUR]]

#for those that cut across the hour mark, split into 2, if it can be more than 1hr, we can update this part to include that possibility
ovlhr <- DT[hr_aft < endDT.event]
ovlhr <- ovlhr[, .(Event, DT.event=c(DT.event, hr_aft), endDT.event=c(hr_aft, endDT.event)), 
    1L:nrow(ovlhr)][, (1L) := NULL]

#append both dataset to get final desired output
rbindlist(list(DT[hr_aft>=endDT.event][, hr_aft := NULL], ovlhr))[order(DT.event)]
```

output:

```
    Event            DT.event         endDT.event
 1:   off 2012-04-27 17:25:13 2012-04-27 17:25:39
 2:    on 2012-04-27 17:25:39 2012-04-27 18:00:00
 3:    on 2012-04-27 18:00:00 2012-04-27 18:03:29
 4:   off 2012-04-27 18:03:29 2012-04-27 18:03:57
 5:    on 2012-04-27 18:03:57 2012-04-27 19:00:00
 6:    on 2012-04-27 19:00:00 2012-04-27 19:41:16
 7:   off 2012-04-27 19:41:16 2012-04-27 19:43:50
 8:    on 2012-04-27 19:43:50 2012-04-27 20:00:00
 9:    on 2012-04-27 20:00:00 2012-04-28 06:23:57
10:   off 2012-04-28 06:23:57 2012-04-28 06:32:13
11:    on 2012-04-28 06:32:13 2012-04-28 06:40:20
12:   off 2012-04-28 06:40:20 2012-04-28 06:40:48
13:    on 2012-04-28 06:40:48 2012-04-28 07:00:00
14:    on 2012-04-28 07:00:00 2012-04-28 08:16:07
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Event   DT.event
off     4/27/12_17:25:13     
on      4/27/12_17:25:39     
off     4/27/12_18:03:29     
on      4/27/12_18:03:57     
off     4/27/12_19:41:16     
on      4/27/12_19:43:50     
off     4/28/12_6:23:57      
on      4/28/12_6:32:13      
off     4/28/12_6:40:20      
on      4/28/12_6:40:48      
off     4/28/12_8:16:07")
```